# HighCharts not giving x-axis values as expected

Tags: highcharts

I am working with HighCharts and I try to pass values, but I don't get the expected results. My idea is to pass two values the first is Date and the second the value for that date.
1. I am using the Highstock model.
2. I try to create an array of arrays, where each element has two values *[a,b]* or in my case a is *a* Date and *b* is the value that I want on the chart. The function that creates the first array looks like this:

```
var results = [];
        for (x = 0; x < data.total_rows; x++) {
            var aValueTmp = parseInt(data.rows[x].key)*1000;
            var aValue = new Date(timeStampTmp);//not needed
            var bValueTmp = data.rows[x].value;
            var bValue = parseInt(valTmp);
            results.push([aValueTemp, bValue]);
        }
        createChart(results);
```

So this part works. createChart is another function where I create the HighChart. The part where I pass the data looks like this:

```
series:[{
    name: 'Measurements',
    data: results
}],
```

**Problem**:
1. So *aValueTemp* gets the date in Epoch format, and then **aValue** calculates it in Unix format. When I pass the data as shown in the code above, then it looks like all the values are from 1 of January.
2. When I switch in my function and pass the *aValueTemp* instead of *aValue* then it is not drawing a line in the chart. But now the date is different 18.January, which again it is not the value I am passing.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You are giving highcharts a Date object, when in fact highcharts needs time in milliseconds. So either use `timeStampTmp` (if it is in ms) or do `timeStampTmp*1000` (if it is in seconds).

Comment: Part of the problem is solved, please take a look at the updated I have just written.

Comment: Your second part of the question is impossible to answer as the question is now. You need to update the question with the full config, and a sample of the input data for people to be able to answer that part. Have a read at how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It was a duplicate. The solution is to multiply the aValueTemp by 1000 so that I get values in ms.

Comment: Then you should accept the duplicate nomination.